# Is there a way to create a widget with configuration wrap and select_range method?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a problem. In Tkinter there are two widgets: Text and Entry. The Text widget has a configuration wrap='word'. And the Entry widget has a method select_range. I need both the wrap configuration and the select_range method in order to select certain parts of a massive text (by select I mean like with the mouse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to combine the features of two different widgets, but there's really no need to do that. All you're asking for is the ability to select a range of text, and the text widget supports that.

The method to select a range of characters is documented. All you need to do is add the tag "sel" to a range of characters.

Comment: @IgorDragushhak: if you're talking about line 1, then it would be `"1.5"` and `"1.11"` This is all described in most tkinter documentation. For example, https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html

Comment: Can I somehow ignore the line part of the tag and select more items then there are in a line?

Comment: @IgorDragushhak: no, otherwise tkinter won't know which characters to highlight. And you can't select characters that don't exist.

Comment: Thank you. I will figure something out with this limitation. I want to write a program for automated tagging of text for text corpuses.

Comment: @IgorDragushhak: what limitation are you talking about? You can literally select anything that's in the widget.